# declare template class within class with same types as parent class

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, ostream

Fancy cout/shift `operator<<` for class in class scope.

```
template <typename X, typename Y> class Foo {
public:
    template <typename A, typename B> class Bar {
        A a;
        B b;
    };

    Bar<X,Y> baba;
};

template <typename V, typename W>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& os, Foo<V,W>::template Bar<V,W> *b) {return os;}
```

This does not compile. But how to do it properly?

---

Error:

```
error: expected template-id for type before ‘*’ token
  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foo<V, W>::template Bar<V, W> *b)
```

Comment: Start by adding a the missing trailing `;` to the `class Bar` definition?

Comment: Does `Foo<V,W>::Bar<A,B>` make sense ? or you always want `Foo<V,W>::Bar<V,W>` ?

Comment: In practice only the latter one will appear, but I guess the first one would be fine.

Comment: `Foo<V,W>::Bar<V,W>` should be `typename Foo<V,W>::Bar<V,W>`.

Comment: @Pradhan: you miss the missing `template` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
template <typename V, typename W>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& os, typename Foo<V,W>::template Bar<V,W> &b) {return os;}
```

but changing the class may be simpler:

```
template <typename X, typename Y> class Foo {
public:
    class Bar {
        X a;
        Y b;
    };

    Bar baba;
};

template <typename V, typename W>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& os, const typename Foo<V,W>::Bar& b) {return os;}
```

The true solution (to avoid problem with type deduction) is to put the free function inside the class:

```
template <typename X, typename Y> class Foo {
public:
    class Bar {
        X a;
        Y b;

        friend
        std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Bar &b) {return os;}
    };

    Bar baba;
};
```

Comment: the first will not work, you can't deduce `Foo<V,W>` based on `Bar<V,W>` (which is the real argument passed in), and `Foo<V,W>` itself is in a non-deduced context

Comment: the second won't work neither, it's also a non-deduced context

Comment: @PiotrS.: It *works*, we just have to explicitly give template argument (which is not user friendly, I agree). Just added the version to avoid this problem.

Comment: @drahnr *"The first code block is what I desired."* it compiles, but `std::cout << &bar;` call doesn't pick your overload